# message header doesn't build

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin-make, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this question has been asked a number of times, and I've gone through and followed the instructions on a number of those answers (for example- [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/306884/custom-message-fails-to-build-no-such-file-or-directory/) and [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/188982/message-headers-wont-build-first/)), as well as in the documentation for building a custom message. Yet still my message header is not building.

This is the error I get:

```
/home/erinline/Documents/testsim/src/m-explore/explore/src/explore.cpp:39:10: fatal error: msg/util.h: No such file or directory


#include <msg/util.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
m-explore/explore/CMakeFiles/explore.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'm-explore/explore/CMakeFiles/explore.dir/src/explore.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [m-explore/explore/CMakeFiles/explore.dir/src/explore.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:23711: recipe for target 'm-explore/explore/CMakeFiles/explore.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [m-explore/explore/CMakeFiles/explore.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(explore_lite)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  actionlib
  actionlib_msgs
  costmap_2d
  geometry_msgs
  map_msgs
  move_base_msgs
  nav_msgs
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  tf
  visualization_msgs
  message_generation
)

add_message_files(
  FILES
  util.msg
)

generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    actionlib_msgs
    geometry_msgs
    map_msgs
    move_base_msgs
    nav_msgs
    std_msgs
    visualization_msgs
    message_runtime
)

###########
## Build ##
###########
# c++11 support required
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
check_cxx_compiler_flag("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

## Specify additional locations of header files
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  include
)

add_executable(explore
  src/costmap_client.cpp
  src/explore.cpp
  src/frontier_search.cpp
)
#add_dependencies(explore ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

add_dependencies(explore explore_lite_generate_messages_cpp)
target_link_libraries(explore ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

#############
## Install ##
#############

# install nodes
install(TARGETS explore
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

# install roslaunch files
install(DIRECTORY launch/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
)

#############
## Testing ##
#############
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  find_package(roslaunch REQUIRED)

  # test all launch files
  roslaunch_add_file_check(launch)
endif()
```

My message is called util.msg, it is in a file called msg within the package file called explore. I must be missing something, since those previous answers seem to work for some folks. Any advice on where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321041/message-header-doesn%27t-build/) by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your `CMakeLists.txt` shows:

> ```
> project(explore_lite)
> ```

```
[..]
```

> 

```
add_message_files(
  FILES
  util.msg
)
```

The error output shows:

> ```
> /home/erinline/Documents/testsim/src/m-explore/explore/src/explore.cpp:39:10: fatal error: msg/util.h: No such file or directory
> ```

> ```
> #include <msg/util.h>
> ```

You write:

> My message is called util.msg, it is in a file called msg within the package file called explore [..]

There are a few discrepancies here:

- according to your build script, the package is actually called `explore_lite`, not `explore`
- the compiler output suggests it's in a directory called `m-explore` (or the package is actually called `m-explore`)

As to why the include fails: message header `#include` lines follow the pattern: `pkg_that_hosts_the_msg/MsgHeader.h`.

In your care this should probably be `explore_lite/util.h`, not `msg/util.h`.

Two additional comments:

1. it might be good to store messages in a separate package (it will make interfacing with your package much easier, as I don't have to build your node in order to use the messages)
2. try to follow [ROS naming guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Names): `util` as a name does not convey much semantics and message (file)names should start with an uppercase character

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kitkatme](https://answers.ros.org/users/40297/kitkatme/) on 2019-04-14**:
thanks so much!! your suggestion to change the include line to `explore_lite/util.h` solved the issue. also thanks for the notes on guidelines! will update my files later.